# How to associate a file type with a (my) Java application on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, file-extension, file-association

I want to be able to double click on textfile.myext and have my java program open and handle the file.

How should I go about making my program accept files that are set as default to open in said program?

What are the steps and what is passed to the program after something is set as default?

Comment: That depends on your operating system.

Comment: This *might* be better-suited to superusers, etc. However, unless there is a duplicate, I think it would be a valuable resource to have on SO (In the past week there has been a similar question for Windows). I have refined to "OSX" in particular, as it will vary by OS. In short the OS must provide some way of "registering" an application with a file type (extension, magic number, etc). In Windows this is done with the registry. I have no idea how it is done in OSX :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), which provides..

> ..splash screens, desktop integration, **file associations,** automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

To see how it is done, visit the [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs), the `filetest.zip` contains the source, launch file and build file. The demo. ..

> ..prompts the user to associate file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`.

If the user asks to open a file, the arguments will be `-open path/to/file.name` or for print it will be `-print path/to/file.name`.

JWS is supplied with the JRE, and works on OS X, Windows & *nix.

Comment: This is great, but I'm not sure how to tell parts away from other parts on that site. The only thing I was expecting though was the arguments. That's all I need, and thanks for the (indirect) answer! :D