# Set a .jar as the default application? (Mac OSX)

Tags: java, macos, jar, default

Is there a way to set a .jar application as the default program to open .blah files on Mac OSX? I know how to set a .app as a default application, but the .app is the only file type not grayed out when you go to choose an application as a default.

What should I do about it?

Comment: .jar is not an application. It's just a java file. You'd set the JVM to be the handler for .blah files, with the .jar loaded as a permanent arg for the jvm call

Comment: *"default program to open .blah files"*  DYM setting a file-association for your app.?

Comment: See also [How to associate a file type with a (my) Java application on OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9659543/418556) (I thought this sounded oddly familiar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [*Java Deployment Options for Mac OS X*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/java/conceptual/java14development/03-javadeployment/javadeployment.html), you can create a *Mac OS X Application Bundle* that "can associate specific document types with your application. This lets users launch your application by double-clicking a document created by your application." See also more [*About Info.plist Keys*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009247).

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Jar using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The launch file provides the ability to set-up a file/content-type association.  Here is a [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) that..

> ..prompts the user to associate file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`. ..

To do that at run-time in a JWS app., look to the [`IntegrationService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html) introduced in 1.6.0_18+.

JWS is designed to work on OS X (and Windows & *nix).